# Delphi functions can't find each other

Tags: delphi

I'm writing a Delphi program which uses multiple functions but encountered a problem My one function named `DivS` uses to my other function `InplementS` in its code and `InplementS` uses `DivS` in its code

Now If I put the `DivS` function's code before `InplementS`, the use of `DivS` in `InplementS` is not marked as error but the use of `InplementS` in `DivS`'s code IS marked as error The same with vice versa

How can I make it work together?

Thanks in advance

Comment: forward declaration?

Comment: @JamesBarrass:  Indeed.  I hope the OP thinks to look it up in the OLH.

Comment: Thanks I added the declension; forward; to my implementation section and it worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possibilities:

- Use the `forward` directive:

  ```
  implementation

  procedure B; forward;

  procedure A;
  begin
    B;
  end;

  procedure B;
  begin
    A;
  end;
  ```
- Declare at least one of them in the interface section:

  ```
  procedure B;

  implementation

  procedure A;
  begin
    B;
  end;

  procedure B;
  begin
    A;
  end;
  ```